# flickAPI: How do I list the sets for my user account?

Tags: python, api, flickr

I wish to list all the sets created by this user along with the set id. I am using flickrApi and Python. Here's my code. The setName is returning "none" in the output.
The elm.get('title') is returning "none".

```
    import flickrapi

api_key = 'APIKEY'
api_secret = 'APISECRET'

flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret)

(token, frob) = flickr.get_token_part_one(perms='write')
if not token: raw_input("Press ENTER after you authorized this program")
flickr.get_token_part_two((token, frob))
try:
    favs = flickr.photosets_getList(user_id='51784048@N00')
    #favs = flickr.favorites_getPublicList(user_id = '51784048@N00')
    for elm in favs.getiterator():
        print ("id: %s secret: %s setname: %s") %(elm.get('id'), elm.get('secret'), elm.get('title')) 
except:
    raise Exception("Some error encountered!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're working with `flickrapi` in Python, it's frequently useful to print the XML which is returned by the API calls in order to see what's going on.  In your example, if you add:

```
 from xml.etree import ElementTree
```

... at the top, and then add:

```
print ElementTree.tostring(favs)
```

... you'll see that the structure returned is:

```
<rsp stat="ok">
<photosets page="1" pages="1" perpage="80" total="80">
    <photoset .../>
    <photoset .../>
    <photoset .../>
    <photoset ...>
</photosets>
</rsp>
```

In a real application, you'd want to check the return status and check the `page` attributes, but to quickly get to what you want, let's just look at the `<photoset>` elements.  To iterate over them, you can change your loop to:

```
for elm in favs.getchildren()[0]:
    print ElementTree.tostring(elm)
```

Then you'll see the structure of each `photoset` element that you'll have to navigate.  For example, one would be:

```
<photoset can_comment="1"
          count_comments="0"
          count_views="34"
          date_create="1156703089"
          date_update="1297462539"
          farm="1"
          id="72157594253605858"
          needs_interstitial="0"
          photos="73" primary="226222345"
          secret="63fde66413"
          server="62"
          videos="0"
          visibility_can_see_set="1">
    <title>Birds</title>
    <description />
</photoset>
```

... so the title is actually stored in a `title` sub-element.  From that, you can see that to get the information that you want, you can do:

```
for elm in favs.getchildren()[0]:
    title = elm.getchildren()[0].text
    print ("id: %s secret: %s setname: %s") %(elm.get('id'), elm.get('secret'), title)
```

... which produces the output:

```
id: 72157600139832705 secret: 4e884f3523 setname: French Creek State Park
id: 72157600047937451 secret: d3c84ed8df setname: Las Vegas
id: 72157594253605858 secret: 63fde66413 setname: Birds
```

etc.